# Pages In Virtual Address Space Equation

Tags: paging, virtual-memory, addressing, page-tables

I have been given the following problem to work out..but not sure I am on the right track..

If a virtual address of 2GB is divided into 4k pages how many pages would exist in the virtual address space.

I have worked it out that if 2<sup>31</sup> = 2GB and 2<sup>12</sup> would equal the 4k page size..

So if I take the 12 bits away from the 31 I would be left with 2<sup>19</sup> pages..

Is that right or am I way off the mark?

Any confirmation/direction (formula) would be appreciated!

Comment: The good old division.

Comment: No the question was as is written..there is nothing else for me to consider but working out how many pages at 4k are in 2GB of logical address space.